# Knight's tour recursion doesn't find a solution

Tags: java, recursion, graph-algorithm, backtracking, knights-tour

Knight's tour was asked before, but I'm still having trouble with it. I'm trying a recursion to visit all cells of chessboard but I can't make more than 52 visits. After that it backtracks and the number of visited cells counts down. Here is my code:

```
public class Ch7E22_3 {
    public static int[][] chess;
    public static int[][] adjacent;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        chess = new int[8][8];
        adjacent = new int[][] { { 2, 1 }, { 2, -1 }, { -2, 1 }, { -2, -1 }, { 1, 2 }, { -1, 2 }, { 1, -2 },
                { -1, -2 } };
        initializeChess();
        move(1, 0, 0);
    }

    private static void move(int cnt, int row, int col) {
        chess[row][col] = cnt;
        if (cnt == (8 * 8)) {
            System.out.println("You moved around all cells: " + cnt);
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                if (((row + adjacent[i][0] >= 0) && (row + adjacent[i][0]) < 8)
                        && ((col + adjacent[i][1] >= 0) && (col + adjacent[i][1] < 8))) {
                    if (chess[row + adjacent[i][0]][col + adjacent[i][1]] == 0) {
                        row = row + adjacent[i][0];
                        col = col + adjacent[i][1];
                        cnt++;
                        System.out.println(row + "  " + col + "  cnt = " + cnt);
                        move(cnt, row, col);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        chess[row][col] = 0;
    }

    private static void initializeChess() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                chess[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don´t know for sure, but isn´t a initialized int array already filled with zeros? So the initializeChess() in you main method is unnecessary.

Comment: @FatTony That's correct; it would only be needed to clear out an already-used array and start over, which this program doesn't do.

Answer (score 2):

A first problem is here:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
```

So, you have that out for loop. Lets assume you enter with cnt at 51.

Now you have

```
if ( ... some overly complicated condition ... ) {
  ... cnt++
  move(cnt,
```

What happens now is: first you make your recursive calls, and probably **each** time right your first if hits. Thus, you increase cnt and recurse again. Therefore your printouts show how cnt is constantly increasing.

But at some point, the recursion **ends** - the if condition doesn't get true any more. So the recursively called method ... ends. But keep in mind: you called that method ... from another call to **move**. And that one might still be looping. And more importantly, **that** move() has its **own** version of cnt.

To see what I mean: change cnt from being a **method local** variable to be a field of your class, similar to your board! When you do that, you will find that your code actually prints:

```
...
3  7  cnt = 52
2  4  cnt = 53
...
2  3  cnt = 64
You moved around all cells: 64
0  4  cnt = 65
...
```

to actually stop later on with

```
4  0  cnt = 126
```

Meaning: printing of cnt is just a side effect of your algorithm not really working correctly!

Finally: I would recommend to break up your if condition into a set of small helper methods, like

```
private static isXyz(...)
```

and to call those methods within that if statement - it would help with readability dramatically!

Comment: It appears that `cnt` is intended to be only a count of the squares (cells) currently visited, not all cells ever visited, so it should never go above 64.

Comment: If I consider `cnt` as a class field, then there are two counters in my class. One of them is a class field cnt the other one is move method parameter `private static void move(int counter, int row, int col) {
        chess[row][col] = cnt; `

Comment: So I suppose you mean that I should count up "counter" on each recursive call.

Comment: What I mean is: you should determine what you intend to do, and then you implement that. Its your code, its your counter, so you should be the one who knows why that counter is there and what its usage is.

Comment: @GhostCat OK! Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Your backtracking is not correct. By the time the last line executes, setting `chess[row][col]` back to zero, `row` and `col` have almost certainly changed.

It would be better to never change `row`, `col`, and `cnt` in your method, but only pass new values into the recursive call. Something like this, although I haven't checked the rest of your logic:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        int nextrow = row + adjacent[i][0];
        int nextcol = col + adjacent[i][1];
        if (nextrow >= 0 && nextrow < 8 &&
                nextcol >= 0 && nextcol < 8) {
            if (chess[nextrow][nextcol] == 0) {
                System.out.println(nextrow + "  " + nextcol + "  cnt = " + (cnt+1));
                move(cnt+1, nextrow, nextcol);
            }
        }
    }
```

To ensure you're consistent in only modifying the values that are passed down to the subsequent recursive call, and never modifying them within the method, you can make the parameters final:

```
private static void move(final int cnt, final int row, final int col) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: If I take cnt as a final variable, I can't count up later on. It will be a constant.

Comment: @Behnaz I may be misunderstanding how you are using `cnt`; I thought you wanted to increment it when you make a move, but return to the previous value of it when backtracking?

Comment: Yes exactly. Sorry if I made you misunderstood.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, I encounter infinite loop when I put cnt+1

Comment: If I take cnt as a final variable, I can't count up later on. It will be a constant